# Build hierarchy in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to build a hierarchy of who reports to who and create the reporting structure for each record.

My raw data would consist of two columns:
e_id and s_id:

and I want to create a variable with a dictionary containing the structure like below. leftmost value of the list would be climbing the hierarchy while the dictionary key is the record e_id value.

```
e_id    s_id    structure
 1                  {1:[null]}
 2        3       {2:[2,3]} circular so infinite sequence
 3        2       {3:[3,2]} circular so infinite sequence
 4        6       {4:[null,1,6]}
 5        4       {5:[null,1,6,4]}
 6        1       {6:[null,1]}
```

From my understanding this would be an apply method, I am just confused with how to set it up to read other rows and return the s_id value of that row.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better way to do this using `networkx` graphs. But here is one simple solution.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'e_id': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   's_id': [None,3,2,6,4,1]})
```

Create a dict with parents and child

```
parents = dict(zip(df.e_id, df.s_id))
```

Function will get the child for each parent passed and then recursively until a circular situation occurs or reaches a None

```
def find_child(x,i):
    if i==0:
        child_list.clear()
    child = parents.get(x)
    if child not in child_list:
        child_list.append(child)
    else:
        return child_list
    if pd.isnull(child)==False:
        find_child(child,1)
        return child_list
```

Loop through the df rows and apply the function for each `e_id`. The second parameter is to distingush between whether to clear the list or not in case of recursive calls

```
child_list = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print({row['e_id']:  find_child(row['e_id'], 0)})
```

Output:

```
{1.0: None}
{2.0: [3.0, 2.0]}
{3.0: [2.0, 3.0]}
{4.0: [6.0, 1.0, nan]}
{5.0: [4.0, 6.0, 1.0, nan]}
{6.0: [1.0, nan]}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!